# How to find out where error occurs in Inno Setup script?

Tags: inno-setup

One of my users sent error report that the installer has crashed with following error:

> Runtime error (at 34:1346): Type Mismatch

The installer uses Inno Setup. The investigation showed that the bug caused error has been contained in installer.iss.

Where can error be located if I know "34:1346" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error location is in the compiled bytecode of your script and as such is pretty much impossible to track back to a line of code.

If they can reproduce it, they should launch your installer with `/log=filename` command line option and you can take a look into such file.